# PostgreSQL aggregate function and missing frame rows

Tags: postgresql, aggregate-functions, window-functions

I'm trying to define a PostgreSQL aggregate function that is aware of rows asked for in the frame clause but that are missing.  Specifically, let's consider an aggregate function `framer` whose job is to return an array consisting of the values aggregated through it, with any missing values in the frame returned as `null`.  So,

```
select
    n,
    v,
    framer(v) over (order by v rows between 2 preceding and 2 following) arr
from (values (1, 3200), (2, 2400), (3, 1600), (4, 2900), (5, 8200)) as v (n, v)
order by v
```

should return

```
"n" "v" "arr"
3   1600    {null,null,1600,2400,2900}
2   2400    {null,1600,2400,2900,3200}
4   2900    {1600,2400,2900,3200,8200}
1   3200    {2400,2900,3200,8200,null}
5   8200    {2900,3200,8200,null,null}
```

Basically I want to grab a range of values around each value, and it's important to me to know if I'm missing any to the left or to the right (or potentially both).  Seems simple enough.  I expected something like this to work:

```
create aggregate framer(anyelement) (
    sfunc = array_append,
    stype = anyarray,
    initcond = '{}'
);
```

but it returns

```
"n" "v" "arr"
3   1600    {1600,2400,2900}
2   2400    {1600,2400,2900,3200}
4   2900    {1600,2400,2900,3200,8200}
1   3200    {2400,2900,3200,8200}
5   8200    {2900,3200,8200}
```

So `sfunc` is really only being called three times when two of the values are missing.

I haven't been able to think of any non-ridiculous way to capture those missing rows.  It seems like there should be a simple solution, like somehow prepending/appending some sentinel nulls to the data before the aggregate runs, or maybe somehow passing in the index (and frame values) as well as the actual value to the function...

I wanted to implement this as an aggregate because it gave the nicest user-facing experience for what I want to do.  Is there any better way?

FWIW, I'm on postgres 9.6.

Answer (score 3):

Ok, this was an interesting one. :)

I created an aggregate `framer(anyarray, anyelement, int)` so we can define the
array size according to the window size.

First we replace `array_append` with our own `framer_msfunc`:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.framer_msfunc(arr anyarray, val anyelement, size_ integer)
 RETURNS anyarray
 LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $function$
DECLARE
    result ALIAS FOR $0;
    null_ val%TYPE := NULL; -- NULL of the same type as `val`
BEGIN

    IF COALESCE(array_length(arr, 1), 0) = 0 THEN
        -- create an array of nulls with the size of `size_`
        result := array_fill(null_, ARRAY[size_]);
    ELSE
        result := arr;
    END IF;

    IF result[size_] IS NULL THEN
        -- first run or after `minvfunc`.
        -- a NULL inserted at the end in `minvfunc` so we want to replace that.
        result[size_] := val;
    ELSE
        -- `minvfunc` not yet called so we just append and drop the first.
        result := (array_append(result, val))[2:];
    END IF;

    RETURN result;

END;
$function$
```

Then we create a `minvfunc` as it is needed for moving aggregates.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.framer_minvfunc(arr anyarray, val anyelement, size_ integer)
 RETURNS anyarray
 LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $function$
BEGIN

    -- drop the first in the array and append a null
    RETURN array_append(arr[2:], NULL);

END;
$function$
```

Then we define the aggregate with the moving aggregate arguments:

```
create aggregate framer(anyelement, int) (
    sfunc = framer_msfunc,
    stype = anyarray,
    msfunc = framer_msfunc,
    mstype = anyarray,
    minvfunc = framer_minvfunc,
    minitcond = '{}'
);
```

We put the `framer_msfunc` as `sfunc` too since `sfunc` is required,
but it doesn't really work. It could be replaced with a fuction takes
the same arguments but actually just calls `array_append` inside so it would actually do something useful.

And here's your example but with a couple more input values.

The frame size should be atleast the size of the window. It doesn't really work with smaller sizes.

```
select
    n,
    v,
    framer(v, 5) over (order by v rows between 2 preceding and 2 following) arr
from (values (1, 3200), (2, 2400), (3, 1600), (4, 2900), (5, 8200), (6, 2333), (7, 1500)) as v (n, v)
order by v
;
 n |  v   |            arr
---+------+----------------------------
 7 | 1500 | {NULL,NULL,1500,1600,2333}
 3 | 1600 | {NULL,1500,1600,2333,2400}
 6 | 2333 | {1500,1600,2333,2400,2900}
 2 | 2400 | {1600,2333,2400,2900,3200}
 4 | 2900 | {2333,2400,2900,3200,8200}
 1 | 3200 | {2400,2900,3200,8200,NULL}
 5 | 8200 | {2900,3200,8200,NULL,NULL}
(7 rows)
```

It would be nice if the size could be inferred from the window's size,
but I coulnd't find if it could be done.

Comment: I really liked this, but it doesn't work when `size_` is larger than the amount of input.  Consider `select n, v, framer(v, 3) over (order by v rows between 1 preceding and 1 following) arr from (values (1, 32), (2, 24)) as v (n, v) order by v;` should return `{null, 24, 32}, {24, 32, null}` but instead returns `{null, 24, 32}, {null, 24, 32}`.  Postgres is calling `framer_msfunc` twice to build the first result, and never again, reusing the answer for the second result.

Because Postgres is willing to cache results, I wonder if there might be any other trick cases where it breaks.

Comment: Ugh... Can't find anything that would skip the cache with window aggregates... Seems like a custom window function written in C could be the solution though.

Comment: upvoted! if you dont mind clarifying what exactly is postges caching in moving aggregate functions?